# dismiss presenting viewController is not working and a warning message is appeared

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have an issue with dismissing the current viewController and presenting another one. I have the current viewController named viewController3 with MKMapView. When I try to open another viewController from viewController3 a warning message says

"Warning: Attempt to present `<ViewController3: 0xb84e270>` on `<ViewController2: 0xb8485e0>` while a presentation is in progress!"

"attempt to dismiss modal view controller whose view does not currently appear. self = `<ViewController2: 0xb8485e0>` modalViewController = `<ViewController3: 0x9b55130>`"

***update :***

**this warning is also shown**

"Warning: Attempt to present `<ViewController4_modified: 0x9b79c70>` on `<ViewController3: 0xb18ebc0>` whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

here is the code in viewController3.m file

```
- (IBAction)testButton:(id)sender
{
ViewController4_modified *VC4 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController4_modified"];

VC4.formUserNameTextInVC3 = self.mapUserNameTextInVC2;

[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

NSLog(@"VC3 is dismissed");

[self presentViewController:VC4 animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

I am also using the same code to go form viewController2 to viewController3.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

instead of using:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

use:

```
[[[self parentViewController] parentViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue that you are dismissing a view at the same time loading a new view. What you should do is load the new view, after you have completed with the dismissal as such:

```
  [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: ^{
          NSLog(@"VC3 is dismissed");
         [self presentViewController:VC4 animated:YES completion:nil];
  }];
```

That way, it will dismiss the current controller, and then load the next one after it has completed.

Comment: I tried it between viewController2 and viewController3 but the problem is when viewController3(the one that has MKMapview) loads from viewController2, it just loads fast and the whole viewController is frozen and is like every thing is disabled :/

Comment: Ok, well in your errors, it seems as if your view for ViewController2 isn't appearing. Is that just a regular viewController?

Comment: in my app, all viewController(s) are regular .. sorry for not explaining clearly, but the problem is in viewController3 ... even the log statement **NSLog(@"VC2 is dismissed")** does not appear

Comment: try changing self.presentingViewController to just self, and see if that workds

Comment: I just have noticed this warning **Warning: Attempt to present <ViewController3: 0x9ab9d30> on <ViewController2: 0xb0cda90> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!**

Comment: that means that you don't have ViewController2 in the hierarchy of your views.

Comment: when I go back to the previous code(the one I posted in question) it works fine but the warning "attempt to dismiss modal view controller ..... " is shown again !

Comment: well alright :) glad I could be of some help, but it's good you solved it :)